# Improper definite integral set-up for a hollow cylinder

Tags: integration

What should be an extremely simple question for some reason is frustrating me with answers that don't seem to make sense in my mind, and I've lost the sanity to ensure that my answer is correct.

[image]

As some quick rough estimates above, I calculated the area as simple rectangles in order to provide bounds on the possible answers that I would be expecting. That all said, my integration over the curve results in answers that are wildly outside my expected bounds. At this point I'm simply plugging the integral into a calculator and determining that I'm failing to properly set up my integral.

Side note: this is not a homework assignment, I'm estimating the required concrete I need for a tiny retaining wall (in cubic inches). Is there a seemingly visible error in the setup for the above integrals? Apologies if quick-fire questions like these aren't appropriate for mathexchange, bit of a hair-pulling day for a topic I thought I understood years back. If the problem lies in something beyond a typo, I'll fix up the question for future readers.

Comment: What function do you integrate in the main integral?

Comment: I integrated the circumference of the circle, admittedly pulling out the constants in front of the integrals. In essence, I integrated `2*pi*r`, multiplied by `(1/4)` (for the quarter circle), and multiplied again `*2` to double the final result. It's just that those constants cancel, hence the grey. `pi` was simply plugged in instead of integrating `theta` Calculating straight from `r dr dt dh` gives the same result.

Comment: I’ve found the error: your calculator interpreted the inner integral as the integral over h, and the outer one it thinks is over r.

Comment: Even correcting for that error, I arrive at `546pi`, which doesn't make much sense to me. How do you add a slope from 3in to 6in on top of a 3-in tall rectangle, and end up with the same area? This is the hair-pulling bit, I've been running between answers while clearly missing something.

Comment: that’s because you didn’t add the slope to your integral at the first place. You have to add a factor to the function you integrate which would account the slope.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow, `dh` in this case was my differential for `height`, which I was plugging in from `3` to `6` as my slope. Is that not correct?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you should integrate the hight function over the area between the walls. So yes, taking h as an independent variable is incorrect.

Comment: In your case, I think $h(r, \theta) = h(\theta)$, and you should integrate $\int_0^\pi \int_{90}^{92} h(\theta) r d\theta dr$. Unfortunately, I can’t say more without knowing $h(\theta)$.

Comment: Aha, I think you've hit the heart of the issue; `h` most certainly is _not_ an independant variable (and very much depends on theta). I have a little brushing up to do myself to get that part of the equation right. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome!

Comment: End result was `546(2 + pi)` from `h(theta) = 3 + 3sin(theta)`!

Comment: yay, it is perfectly consistent with the estimates